# IIS10 de-evolved for SSL CA Certs all appear as Issued to: localhost

Tags: ssl, iis

I recently added a fourth SSL "COMODO RSA" cert to my IIS10 Server 2016.

This is a dev server so we have one IP address and use host headers for a variety of domains in IIS.

If i inspect bindings they are tied to the correct certificate and also the checkbox for "Require Server Name Indication" is on.

When the site is accessed the browse has a ssl warning and if inspect the cert it says "Issued to: localhost" .

I used mmc to look at the servers Local Computer \ Personal \ Certificates and they are there.   I have restarted iis , restarted the server, reissued cert and the issue persists.

What else can i check?

Comment: Does `netsh http show sslcert` look ok? (It lists what has been configured with http.sys, rather than what is configured in IIS)

Comment: Thanks - from that result i assume i need to focus on the IP port that is not 0.0.0.0:#####   So that leaves me with looking at some Certificate Store Name being "My"  and some being "WebHosting" and there are two certificates at the top that do not have any Hostname:port and instead have IP:port.    So for the ones that are IP:port - are they overriding?  ex:     IP:port                      : 172.16.10.131:443    Certificate Hash             : f4ee064e26b5b5586d8db6c98931ee06230d8ab1

Comment: should i be trying to find a way to remove the two entries with no host header?

Comment: That sounds like something that would be worth investigating, at least. Particularly if one of those certs has a fingerprint that matches the one that is actually used

Comment: In most cases if you only use SNI bindings, you should get rid of IP based bindings, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/https-binding.html#background That should expose what exactly was wrongly configured on your machine. Try to first locate the certificate (CN=localhost) and then figure out why it is sent by IIS.

Comment: I returned to the problem machine.  Removed all four of the SSL Certs (I used Jexus instead of the two methods last time tried repeatedly -  IIS UI and sometimes certificate snap in method used before). I re-ran “netsh http show sslcert” and nothing was tied to the 172.16.. Ip any more. I carefully reloaded from IIS Manager (“Complete Certificate Request” and pointed to the *.p7b files) and tested first domain fine - then added the other 3 domains and all is working.

Comment: When it is now working “netsh http show sslcert” has a single binding with ip address and 443 (lines removed for readability):

Comment: IP:port                      : 172.16.#.#:443
    Certificate Store Name       : My

    Hostname:port                : dev.????rep.com:443
    Certificate Store Name       : My

    Hostname:port                : www.????eom.com:443
    Certificate Store Name       : My

    Hostname:port                : dev.????eady.com:443
    Certificate Store Name       : My

    Hostname:port                : dev4.????ter.com:443
    Certificate Store Name       : My

    Hostname:port                : ????eom.com:443
    Certificate Store Name       : My

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I returned to the problem machine.  Removed all four of the SSL Certs (I used Jexus instead of the two methods last time tried repeatedly -  IIS UI and sometimes certificate snap in method used before). I re-ran “netsh http show sslcert” and nothing was tied to the 172.16.. Ip any more. I carefully reloaded from IIS Manager (“Complete Certificate Request” and pointed to the *.p7b files) and tested first domain fine - then added the other 3 domains and all is working.

When it is now working “netsh http show sslcert” has a single binding with ip address and 443 (lines removed for readability):

```
IP:port                      : 172.16.#.#:443
Certificate Store Name       : My

Hostname:port                : dev.????rep.com:443
Certificate Store Name       : My

Hostname:port                : www.????eom.com:443
Certificate Store Name       : My

Hostname:port                : dev.????eady.com:443
Certificate Store Name       : My

Hostname:port                : dev4.????ter.com:443
Certificate Store Name       : My

Hostname:port                : ????eom.com:443
Certificate Store Name       : My
```